# Email address is to big for navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with a site that I'm building. I have a navigation bar on my website and I'm trying to replace the menu item "profile" with the email address from the logged-in user. It works just fine, the email is shown but the only problem is that the email (depends on email length) is too big for the navigation bar item. Can I fix this in CSS or JavaScript?

To change the menu item "profile" to the email address I used a script inside the HTML (so not a separate file)

What works:

- I can put the email variable into my HTML

What doesn't work:

- The email variable is not

Link to my website:

https://runes-smart-home.web.app

And you can log in with those credentials:

> Email: thanksforhelping@stackoverflow.com (I took a long email by purpose)
>
> Password: Thanks123!

Screenshot:
[image]
Thanks for helping!

Comment: btw: the email address is not real but works to login with...

Comment: Why do you want to show the mail address at all? The container is only 150px wide. There won't be many addresses short enough for that.

Comment: If you need help with code, provide a [mcve], if you can't, this question is off-topic.

Comment: @Andreas, can I change the container to the width from the email + ... px?

Comment: use `css ellipsis` to truncate the overflow characters

Comment: Can we have a screenshot or fiddle of your related issue?

Comment: I added a screenshot @SaurabhLP

Comment: Generate a fiddle for your issue and also tell me which framework you are using on that website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `text-overflow` property in css. The `text-overflow` CSS property sets how hidden overflow content is signaled to users.

In addition you could add a `title` attribute to show a tooltip on mouse over.
Here is an example how to use it:

HTML

```
<p class="overflow-ellipsis" title="thanksforhelping@stackoverflow.com">thanksforhelping@stackoverflow.com</p>
```

CSS

```
.overflow-ellipsis {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Here are some other approaches
https://jsfiddle.net/api/mdn/

This could be your outcome:

[image: Posible result]

Answer (score 0):

You have to put this code in your html. it will helps you.
Output of this code is ,if email is too large than dots is appear and on hover full email is display.

```
<a href="#0" id="profile" style="text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden;"
 title="thanksforhelping@stackoverflow.com">thanksforhelping@stackoverflow.com</a>
```